# VimL/Vimscript: how to access local variable of outer function from its inner function?

Tags: vimscript, functions, variables

I posted this question on stackoverflow already, but realized afterwards that it's probably better to ask here.

So I have a function of the following form:

```
function! s:my_function(dict_arg)
    let darg = copy(a:dict_arg)

    func! my_inner_func(cond)
        if a:cond ==# 'a'
            execute darg.a
        elseif a:cond ==# 'b'
            execute darg.b
        elseif a:cond ==# 'c'
            execute darg.c
        endif
    endfunc

    return function('my_inner_func')
endfunc
```

Where the argument passed to the `dict_arg` parameter will be some dict keyed with `a`, `b` and `c`, with their respective values being strings representing Ex commands that will be executed depending on the specific `cond` (condition).

The purpose of the outer function `s:my_function` is to generate a Funcref that will execute the appropriate Ex command (`darg.a`, `darg.b` or `darg.c`) based on the `cond`, which is itself determined elsewhere by other variables.

**So my problem is that I don't know how to reference the local variable `darg` defined in the scope of `s:my_function` from within `my_inner_func`.** When the function is called, I get the error `E121: Undefined variable: darg`. It also doesn't work (same error) if I don't define the local variable `darg`, and instead just try to do `execute a:dict_arg.b` for instance.

I can get around it by defining `darg` to be global, as in `let g:darg = copy(a:dict_arg)`, then later doing `execute g:darg.a`. But of course, I'd like to avoid that.

In something like Python, this type of lexical scope resolution is automatic. But VimL is well.. VimL. Any help or pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58737941/viml-vimscript-how-to-access-local-variable-of-outer-function-from-its-inner-fu; please don't cross-post in parallel!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I though it wasn't possible, but I was wrong.

See `:h :func-closure`

You need to patch two things:

- add `closure` at the end of the inner of the function declaration
- respect the usual naming conventions

For instance

```
function! s:my_function(dict_arg)
    let darg = copy(a:dict_arg)

    func! s:my_inner_func(cond) closure
      return darg[a:cond]
    endfunc

    return function('s:my_inner_func')
endfunc

let g:F = s:my_function({'a': 42, 'b': 5, 'c': 'str'})
```

Comment: Excellent! That was it.